# Insert two or more rows into view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one instead of trigger for inserting, deleting and updating my view.
I have some issue with inserting two and more rows.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastId INT

    INSERT INTO Sales.CreditCard
    SELECT
        i.CardType,
        i.CardNumber,
        i.ExpMonth,
        i.ExpYear,
        GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i

    SELECT @LastId = @@IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO Sales.PersonCreditCard
        (BusinessEntityID,
        CreditCardID,
        ModifiedDate)
    SELECT
        i.BusinessEntityID,
        @LastId,
        GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i
END
```

`SELECT @LastId = @@IDENTITY` gets `ID` of the last row, but I insert two or more. How I can change this script to inserting two and more rows?

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I solved my issue, but I am not sure that it's a great solution. What do you think about it?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastId TABLE (ID INT, Number NVARCHAR(25))

    INSERT INTO Sales.CreditCard
        OUTPUT inserted.CreditCardID, inserted.CardNumber INTO @LastId
    SELECT
        i.CardType,
        i.CardNumber,
        i.ExpMonth,
        i.ExpYear,
        GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i

    INSERT INTO Sales.PersonCreditCard
        (BusinessEntityID,
        CreditCardID,
        ModifiedDate)
    SELECT
        i.BusinessEntityID,
        ID,
        GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN @LastId AS l
        ON l.Number = i.CardNumber
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use cursor.

```
Declare @cardtype int,
Declare @cardnumber int ,
Declare @expmonth int,
Declare @expyear int,
Declare @cursor CURSOR

Set @cursor = cursor FAST_FORWARD
for

select i.CardType,i.CardNumber,i.ExpMonth,i.ExpYear,GETDATE()   from        inserted i

Open cursor

FETCH NEXT from @cursor into @cardtype, @cardnumber, @expmonth, @expyear

WHILE @@fetch_status=0
BEGIN
  -- your statement
 FETCH NEXT from  @cursor into @cardtype, @cardnumber, @expmonth,   @expyear

END
close @cursor
deallocate @cursor
```